# What's the structure of .arm.extab entry in armcc?

Tags: c++, arm, keil, armcc

I'm trying to understand exactly how the exception table (`.arm.extab`) works.
I'm aware that this is compiler dependent, so I'll restrict myself to armcc (as I'm using Keil).

A typical entry in the table looks something like:
`b0aa0380 2a002c00 01000000 00000000`

To my understanding, the first word encodes instructions for the personality routine, while the third word is a `R_ARM_PREL31` relocation to the start of the catch block.

What baffles me is the second word - it appears to be split into 2 shorts, the second of which measures some distance from the start of the throwing function, but I'm not sure exactly to what (nor what the first short does).

Is there any place where the structure of these entries is documented?

I've found 2 relevant documents, but as far as I can see they have no compiler-dependent information, so they're not sufficient:

- https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/releases/download/2022Q1/aaelf32.pdf
- https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/releases/download/2022Q1/ehabi32.pdf

Comment: Are you sure you have the byte ordering correct. Ie, the first value is `0xb0aa0380` and not the litte-endian `0x8003aab0`?

Comment: I found that both g++ and clang use the 'generic' method.  For instance _Unwind_Control_Block.exception_class is "GNUCC++\0", "CLNGC++\0", or "ARM\0C++\0".  [clang](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxxabi/blob/master/src/cxa_exception.cpp), [gcc](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/unwind-cxx.h#L262)  This allows operability.  libgcc/libsupc++ have configuration to change the exception method, but it defaults to the one in the *ehabi* document.  I can't see why keil would do something else, but it is possible.

Comment: The links are out of date (both leading to a 404), but I'm not sure about editing newer ones in, because I don't think there are any URLs that always point to the "latest" versions of them.

Comment: The first one is a link to "ELF for the ARM Architecture." The current version can be found at https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/releases/download/2022Q1/aaelf32.pdf - and it looks like there's always a link to the latest if you go to https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/releases and do a Ctrl-F for the document title.

Comment: The second document is "Exception Handling ABI for the Arm®Architecture". Again, the latest download link can be found at https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/releases - and the current version of the document is https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/releases/download/2022Q1/ehabi32.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you happen to have the byte ordering missed up, the below applies.  Some information is probably useful even if the byte-order is correct in your original example.

---

`extab` and `exidx` are sections added by the AAPCS which is a newer ARM ABI.

For the older APCS, the frame pointer or `fp` is a root of a linked of the active routine back to the main routine (or `_start`).  With AAPCS records are created and placed in the `exidx` and `extab` sections.  These are needed to unwind stacks (and resources) when the `fp` is used as a generic register.

The `exidx` is an ordered table of routine start addresses and an `extab` index (or can't unwind).  A `PC` (program counter) can be examined and search via the table to find the corresponding `extab` entry.

The [ARM EHABI](https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/releases/download/2022Q1/ehabi32.pdf) documentation has a section 7 on *Exception-handling Table entries*.  These are `extab` entries and you can at least start from there to learn more.  There are two defined,

1. Generic (or C++)
2. ARM compact

The *compact* model will be used for most 'C' code.  There are no objects to be destroyed on the stack as with C++.  The hex `8003aab0` gives,

- `1000`b for the leading nibble, so this is compact.
- `0000`b for the index. *Su16—Short*
- `03`h - pop 16 bytes, some locals or padding.
- `aa`h - pop r4-r6
- `b0`h - finish

*Table 4, ARM-defined frame-unwinding instructions* gives the unwinding data of each byte.

The next is `0x002c002a` which is an offset to the *generic* personality routine.  The next four values should be the *8.2 Data Structures*, which are a size and should be zero...  Next would be stride and then a four byte object type info.  The offset 0x2c002a would be to call the objects destructor or some sort of wrapper to do this.

---

I think all C++ code is intended to use this *Generic* method.  Other methods are for different languages and **NOT** compilers.

Related Q/A and links:

- [Arm exidx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527256/when-is-arm-exidx-is-used) - about the exidx.
- [ARM link and frame pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752188/arm-link-register-and-frame-pointer) - situation for older APCS and many AAPCS functions.
- [Linux ARM Unwind](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/unwind.c) - sample unwinding code for 'C'.
- [prel31](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578934/longptr-1-1) - SO Q/A on prel31 in Linux code above.
- [Generating unwind in ARM gnu assembler](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/as/ARM-Unwinding-Tutorial.html)
- [gas ARM directives](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/as/ARM-Directives.html) See: `.cantunwind`, `.vsave`, etc.